# javascript object is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting "*map is undefined*", not sure why.
Am I passing a wrong variable, or is `myMap` wrongly declared?

```
var myMap = new Object();
$(things).each(function(){
   var thing= this.attributes.things.Value;
   alert("thing= " + thing);
   var totalThings= myMap[thing];
   alert("totalThings= " + totalThings);                
});
```

Comment: It seems like you're accessing `thing` field of an empty object: `myMap[thing]`

Comment: What error message exactly are you getting? `myMap` looks OK apart from that you could have shortened the constructor invocation to a `{}` literal

Comment: I don't see anything called `map` in that snippet.

Comment: true that, what is thing by the way?

Comment: @kangoroo thing is a string

Comment: Didn't you notice that the `.each` callback never runs? (because the object is empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are `myMap` is defined, but `myMap[thing]` is not (since it's a virgin object with no properties). And since you're *getting* the value (and not *setting* it) you're getting an error.

```
// virgin object
var myObj = new Object();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj)); // "{}"

// therefore property "foo" doesn't exist
console.log(myObj['foo']);          // undefined

// but if we add it:
myObj['foo'] = 'bar';

// now it exists
console.log(myObj['foo']);          // "bar"
```

Comment: "And since you're getting the value (and not setting it) you're getting an error.". Trying to get an undefined property doesn't throw an error, it simply returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
function myMap( thing ){
// properties and defaults 
this.thing = thing || 'default'
}

var myMapInstance = new myMap(whateverTheThingIs);
```

Answer (score 0):

if thing is a string, may be you were trying to do:

```
myMap[things] = thing;
alert("totalThings = " + JSON.stringify(myMap, null, 4));
```